# How to exclude SLF4J binding from gradle-api-4.10.jar?

Tags: windows, gradle, kotlin, classpath, slf4j

I use `logback` as dependency in my project and get the following output:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:~/.gradle/caches/4.10/generated-gradle-jars/gradle-api-4.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/7c4f3c474fb2c041d8028740440937705ebb473a/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.gradle.internal.logging.slf4j.OutputEventListenerBackedLoggerContext]
```

I read a lot of similar questions and answers. Most of them advice to add corresponding `exclude` to extra dependency. But I can't imagine which of these are relevant to `gradle-api-4.10.jar`. Looking through dependency tree also yielded no result.

Comment: Same thing happens with Gradle 5.6.2. Do you have explicit dependencies with Gradle API or Testkit?